# Having a little trouble converting this SQL script to LINQ

Tags: linq

Having a little trouble converting this SQL script to linq. The "fn_Split_t" function simply splits a comma separated value. The part that is confusing me is the group by there as that seems to throw off everything that follows it.

```
    declare @count int
    select @count = COUNT(*) from  dbo.fn_Split_t(@portfolios)
    select 
         cc.CustodianCommentId
        ,cc.[Message]
        ,Symbol = NULL
        ,cc.DateStamp
        ,cc.AppUser
        ,PositionDate = @date
        ,cc.[Status]
        ,cc.Category
        ,cc.[Group]
    from dbo.CustodianComment cc
    join dbo.CustodianCommentPortfolio ccp on ccp.CustodianCommentId = cc.CustodianCommentId
    join dbo.CustodianPortfolio cp on ccp.CustodianPorfolioId = cp.CustodianPortfolioId
    join dbo.fn_Split_t(@portfolios) s on s.items = cp.PortfolioCode
    where  cp.PositionDate = @date 
    group by cc.CustodianCommentId,  cc.[Message], cc.DateStamp, cc.AppUser, cc.[Status], cc.Category, cc.[Group]
    having count(cc.CustodianCommentId) = @count
    order by cc.DateStamp desc
```

Attempt number one resulted in the following:

```
from c in Context.Comments
join pc in Context.PortfolioComments on c.CommentId equals pc.CommentId
join p in Context.Portfolios on pc.PortfolioId equals p.PortfolioId
where portfolios.Contains(p.PortfolioCode)
&& p.PositionDate == EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(date)
group c by c.CommentId into g
where g.Count() > portfolios.Count()
select new
{
   CommentId = c.CommentId,

   Message = c.Message,
   DateStamp = c.DateStamp,
   AppUser = c.AppUser,
   PositionDate = p.PositionDate,
   Status = c.Status,
   Category = c.Category,
   CategoryId = c.CategoryId,
   Group = c.Group
}
```

However this doesn't work because it says c in the anonymous object is not in scope. portfolios by the way is the same csv string that would have been passed to the @portfolios in the SQL script. I'm am kinda stuck on this one right now so any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
 string[] portfoliosArray = portfolios.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

 from ... in ...
    where portoliosArray.Contains(p.PortfolioCode)
    select ...
```

And you might need to trim the entries when the list of portfolio codes contains spaces or other whitespace:

```
 string[] portfoliosArray = portfolios.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
       .Select(s => s.Trim()).Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)).ToArray();
```

Reading from your original SQL, you might need:

```
    where portfoliosArray.All(p => c.PortFolios.PortfolioCode)
```

Or:

```
    where c.Portfolios.All(p => portfoliosArray.Contains(p.Portfolio.Code))
```

Though I'm not entirely sure on your requirement there.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm sorry I forgot to mention the CSV is already being split into a string array. That part of it actually seems to be working fine. The issue I am having is in creating a type after the group by, which says its "out of scope." The data in comment is a one to many to portfoliocomments, which is a many to one to portfolio. The system however, allows you to add a single to many portfolios. This script is intended to get one record that represents the many comments hence the group by. After explaining that, I'm wondering if a simple distinct() would work?

Comment: Bascially you hae a comments table, a relationship table, and a portfolios table. You can add a comment to a single portfolio, which will create a single entry in the relationship table, and a single entry in the comments table. OR you can you add a comment to a group of portfolios, which will create many entries in the relationship table, and a single entry in the comments table. However when displaying the "group" as a single result set I only want to show the shared comment once.

Comment: One more thing, I omitted something from the original sproc because I didn't think it was relevant at the time.(See the edit above) Turns out that may have been the reason for the "group by". It looks like the "Symbol" field, although null for this sproc can sometimes contain a different value, even on portfolios that would share the same comment, so a simple distinct wouldn't work.